# This question is based on application of derivatives and i'm getting different answers by different approaches!

Tags: functions, derivatives

> Suppose you have a function
> $$f(x)=|x\ln(x)|$$
> Prove that $$f'(x+2) - f'(x) <2$$ for all $x>1$

My first approach:

$f(x)= x\ln(x) ; x>1$
Therefore,
$f'(x)= \ln(x) +1$
also $f''(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

So let,
$g(x)=f'(x+2) - f'(x) = \ln(\frac{x+2}{x})$
When we differentiate $g(x)$ with respect to $x$, the quantity is always negative so $g(x)$ is decreasing. So $g(x)<g(1)$ which comes out to be $\ln 3$.

Second approach:
We use Lagrange mean value theorem on $f'(x)$ on the interval $[x,x+2]$
I'll not go much into the detail,
but the expression is:

$$ \frac{f'(x+2) - f'(x)}{2}= f''(c)$$
for some $c$ in $[x,x+2]$.
Okay now $f''(c)<f''(1)$ since $f''(x)=\frac{1}{x}$
The given statement gets proved by using LMVT.
Have I made a terrible mistake in my first approach? This is confusing me!

Comment: $f(x)$ is defined with absolute value?

Comment: yes but the question focuses on values of x>1

Comment: I see... you are right but I think it's a little strange for me.

Comment: I would suggest you use different variable for function's input and the domain you take. Like put as $\left[ \epislon , \epsilon+2 \right]$ . It'll reduce confusion

Comment: I don't get it, why do you think you have made a mistake? Like in what way do you think the second approach is not consistent with th efirst

Comment: the second approach would never come up in my mind in an exam but to prove that's the only way, and i would be in a confused state of mind whether there is some error in my method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. My guess is that the person who created this problem only had the second approach in mind. But your first approach (which would have been my approach) works too, and it gives a better bound.